# LoadLibrary fails with error code 14007

Tags: c++, loadlibrary

When I try to load a DLL using `LoadLibrary`, the handle is not null but the `GetLastError` is returning 14007. 
Any ideas?

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms681384%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) says:

```
ERROR_SXS_KEY_NOT_FOUND
14007 (0x36B7)
The requested lookup key was not found in any active activation context
```

HMODULE handle = LoadLibrary("mydll.dll");
r = GetLastError();
if(!handle)
    return 0;

Answer (score 1):

The error code is not always reset on success.

First and foremost, to find out whether a function call succeeded, you follow the semantics noted in the documentation. In this case, whether `LoadLibrary` returns a valid handle.

You've indicated that it does, so the result of `GetLastError` is not relevant. It could be the result from some *previous* call that failed.

From [the `GetLastError` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679360%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> The return value is the calling thread's last-error code.
>
> The Return Value section of the documentation for each function that sets the last-error code notes the conditions under which the function sets the last-error code. Most functions that set the thread's last-error code set it when they fail. However, some functions also set the last-error code when they succeed. **If the function is not documented to set the last-error code, the value returned by this function is simply the most recent last-error code to have been set; some functions set the last-error code to 0 on success and others do not.**

I can't see anything in [the `LoadLibrary` documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) suggesting that the error code is set to 0 on success, meaning it's meaningless in your case.

Comment: What puzzles me is I have put GetLastError in the trace at various locations and have stepped though the code, the error pops up right after the call to LoadLibrary.

Comment: @Syler: I don't understand what you mean by "popping up". Can you be more specific? How does this relate to the semantics that I explained above?

Comment: @Syler, It could have resulted from `LoadLibrary` calling another function and that setting it, `LoadLibrary` handling it, and you getting a valid handle back.

Comment: Yep true. The important thing is that `LoadLibrary` did not return `NULL`, so there is no failure to get information about.

Comment: Very possibly the error code is from something inside `LoadLibrary` looking for an SxS DLL of that name.

Comment: ok i'll leave it assuming as long as loadlibrary did not return NULL everything went fine. Though when I try call loadlibrary in another program, i dont get any errors and I have stepped through put debug statements.

Comment: @Syler That's right. If LoadLibrary succeeds, then GetLastError is meaningless and undefined. It could legally return `rand()` after a successful LoadLibrary.